# Creating square, sawtooth and triangle wave in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, trigonometry, synthesizer

I am trying to generate different wave shapes for a simple wavetable synth iOS app I am working on. This is how I am generating the sine wave:

```
        if (waveType == 1) // sine wave
    {
        //NSLog(@"sine in AU");
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            float x = 0.0;        // default to silence
            if (toneCount > 0)  // or create a sinewave
            {
                x = testVolume * sinf(ph);
                ph = ph + dp;

                if (ph > M_PI) { ph -= 2.0 * M_PI; } // sine wave

                toneCount -= 1;    // decrement tone length counter
            }
            if (ptrLeft  != NULL){
                ptrLeft[ i] = x;
            }
            if (ptrRight != NULL) {
                ptrRight[i] = x;
            }
        }
    }
```

For a square wave I was assuming this would work but it hasn't:

```
if (ph > M_PI) { 
ph -= 2.0 * M_PI;
ph >= 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;
}
```

How would I go about creating sawtooth and triangles waves and where is the square wave going wrong?

Thanks, I'm new to iOS programming and love working with audio.

Answer (score 0):

For starters think about your line

```
if (ph > M_PI) { ph -= 2.0 * M_PI; } // sine wave
```

`ph` is your input into your sin function which is some value in radians ... be aware that sin function will automatically handle values greater than 2 * PI it will simply wrap it around so no need to manage your `ph` variable other then simply incrementing it

Regarding your square wave ... keep in mind your output has only two values low or high ... do not drive the toggle between low/high by value of the curve

```
if (ph > M_PI) { 
    ph -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    ph >= 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;
}
```

keep in mind that as you increment your outer loop `i` you are incrementing `ph` which you are using to determine where you are in your PI cycles which is OK however that same `ph` then cannot also be input to sin(ph) as well ... something else must get fed into sin() or else something else maintains your sample position in your PI cycle ... you are mistakenly conflating two responsibilities into a single variable

In above if code block think about when you must perform the toggle from low to high or back from high to low ... does it happen at M_PI ?  how many such toggles happen per cycle ?  when ?   perhaps you need an additional if test to determine when to perform that toggle ... in your sin curve algorithm you are already managing ph must you handle square wave ph differently or leave ph logic the same ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I ended up figuring out that like you said, i was over using ph and needed to leave that to determine where in the PI cycle I am at. So i used x to create the waveforms instead.                              A follow up question: when I am running two oscillators where one is a sine wave and the other is a square, when i try to sum them it sounds far more harsh than how a normal wavetable synth like Massive sounds. Heres what I am working with if you have any advice. Thanks again.

Comment: x = testVolume * sinf(ph); // sine wave                                                      y = testVolume * sinf(ph) >=0 ? 1.0 : -1.0; // square wave                            float z = yn * ( (x*0.5) + (y*0.5) ); where z is the output

Comment: that z equation looks good except what is yn ?   do not think its needed unless its some stretch factor

Comment: I suggest you visualize your output audio ... checkout tool called Audacity which will display the audio as a curve which is essential when manipulating audio ... it lets you zoom in to view all the curve details ... you can also write code to plot the curve

Comment: my apologies for not including any comments about yn, it is a difference equation for an IIR filter that I am using to filter the signal! I haven't gotten it working quite properly yet because im figuring out how to get the "output" of the generated waves as an input to the filter, but I will update when I have! Also, will start looking into plotting the curve to see exactly where Im going wrong. Thanks again.